# Unable to get image from URL at website

Tags: google-chrome, internet, url

When I go to this web-site - http://ships.carnivalentertainment.com/#ship/carnival-inspiration/cameras - and then right click on one of the two ship cams, and open image in a new tab- it works fine.  But if I select 'copy image address' and paste it into a new tab to view the image, it doesn't work.  The URL matches the one from 'open image in a new window' - but times out.  Can't figure this out.  What am I missing?

Comment: Yup, same here. Even if I copy the url after opening it in another window from the menu, it will not work on a new tab, strange, DNS error.

Comment: Please provide the image's URL to get a good answer.  I tried to follow your instructions in both Google Chrome and Firefox and neither gave me an option to open or copy the image URL.  I strongly suspect that they block it intentionally based on the referer.

Comment: I did it again and url changed, so its dynamic. First one [I got this address](http://ec2-54-236-225-221.compute-1.amazonaws.com/~carnivalcam/ship13img1.jpg?t=Sat%20Apr%2030%202016%2012:03:12%20GMT-0500%20(Central%20Daylight%20Time)) Second time [this one](http://ec2-54-236-225-221.compute-1.amazonaws.com/~carnivalcam/ship13img1.jpg)

Comment: So are you wanting to download the image? @Mike Weber

Comment: @JuliePelletier - http://ec2-54-236-225-221.compute-1.amazonaws.com/~carnivalcam/ship13img1.jpg?t=Sat%20Apr%2030%202016%2009:27:24%20GMT-0700%20(Pacific%20Daylight%20Time)

Comment: @Moab - Yes - I have an application that collects web-cam images from a url - and this one URL is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

They obviously purposefully prevent you from accessing their images directly with a few different tricks.  It's their site so it's their right to control that.

They apparently make use of cookies and referer, but they might even have other tricks up their sleeves that deserve to be kept private.

Comment: I can save any of those images I want, I think what they do is to prevent linking to the images directly.

Comment: Indeed.  There is no way to completely prevent someone from saving them as it would also prevent viewing them.  Once you view them, they're already on your computer.

Comment: Some are easy as "save image as" but some you have to do a page source and get the url it is pulling the image from, if none of that works a screenshot of the image in the browser,,,you are correct, if you can see it you can copy it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what it needs:

Referer:http://ships.carnivalentertainment.com/

Looked at the request and saw this, and it resolved my issue.